# Unable to update contact details in CC from parties involved screen

Tags: guidewire, gosu

Unable to update contactmanager contacts in claimcenter from parties involved screen. It tries to insert record in contact table but it should have update the existing contact. Getting below error message

com.guidewire.pl.system.exception.DBException: Failed to execute a batch update
at com.guidewire.pl.system.transaction.ConnectionHandler.newDbException(ConnectionHandler.java:1422) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.transaction.ConnectionHandler.executeBatchUpdate(ConnectionHandler.java:871) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.database.entitywriter.TableWriterImpl.insert(TableWriterImpl.java:94) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.database.entitywriter.DatabaseEntityWriterImpl.insert(DatabaseEntityWriterImpl.java:68) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.database.DatabaseChangedBeanWriter.writeBeanInserts(DatabaseChangedBeanWriter.java:296) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.database.DatabaseChangedBeanWriter.writeBeanChanges(DatabaseChangedBeanWriter.java:234) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.database.DatabaseChangedBeanWriter.writeChangedBeans(DatabaseChangedBeanWriter.java:81) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.bundle.BundleWriter.commitBundle(BundleWriter.java:146) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938) [jetty-util-9.4.30.v20200611.jar:9.4.30.v20200611]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal value for key, bean class = entity.CompanyVendor, id = -489001
at com.guidewire.pl.system.database.impl.DBRestriction.compare(DBRestriction.java:164) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.database.impl.DBRestriction.compareEquals(DBRestriction.java:153) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.database.entitywriter.TableWriterImpl.checkForDuplicateKeyInDatabase(TableWriterImpl.java:694) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.database.entitywriter.TableWriterImpl.checkForDuplicateKeyExceptionForMostDBs(TableWriterImpl.java:638) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.database.entitywriter.TableWriterImpl.checkForDuplicateKeyException(TableWriterImpl.java:357) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.database.entitywriter.TableWriterImpl.insert(TableWriterImpl.java:96) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.database.entitywriter.DatabaseEntityWriterImpl.insert(DatabaseEntityWriterImpl.java:68) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.database.DatabaseChangedBeanWriter.writeBeanInserts(DatabaseChangedBeanWriter.java:296) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.database.DatabaseChangedBeanWriter.writeBeanChanges(DatabaseChangedBeanWriter.java:234) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.database.DatabaseChangedBeanWriter.writeChangedBeans(DatabaseChangedBeanWriter.java:81) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.bundle.BundleWriter.commitBundle(BundleWriter.java:146) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.transaction.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:111) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.transaction.SessionImpl.commit(SessionImpl.java:169) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.transaction.TransactionManagerImpl.execute(TransactionManagerImpl.java:94) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__cc_contac__Conta__6231487C". The conflict occurred in database "cc_v8backup", table "dbo.cc_contact", column 'ID'.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:2075) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre11.jar:?]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:242) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:242) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.database.jdbcwrappers.PreparedStatementDebugHandler.executeBatch(PreparedStatementDebugHandler.java:371) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor193.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.database.jdbcwrappers.StatementDebugHandler.invoke(StatementDebugHandler.java:66) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.executeBatch(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.transaction.ConnectionHandler.executeBatchUpdate(ConnectionHandler.java:857) ~[pl-10.101.0.jar:?]
... 78 more

Answer (score 2):

You need look for this constraint "FK__cc_contac__Conta__6231487C" in db to understant the error.

It is in the stacktrace

> Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__cc_contac__Conta__6231487C". The conflict occurred in database "cc_v8backup", table "dbo.cc_contact", column 'ID'